# BeautifulSoup: Finding a specific URL in html and printing

Tags: python, screen-scraping, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, mechanize

Ok, so I have this html-page (full of different urls), where I want to grab a single url and print it.

The webpage is: https://bdkv2.borger.dk/foa/Sider/default.aspx?fk=22&foaid=11523251

I want to print the url www.albertslund.dk

It looks like this in the source code:

```
<a href="http://www.albertslund.dk" id="_uscAncHomesite" target="_blank"><strong><span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_FormControlHandler1__uscShowDataAuthorityDetails__uscLblHomesite">http://www.albertslund.dk</span></strong></a>
```

When I try to grab it and print it by using it's ID (using BeautifulSoup and Mechanize), it just returns an empty list. I would like to grab the URL using the ID, because I'm scraping a bunch of similar sites, where the things that I want have the same ID.

```
kommuneside = br.open(https://bdkv2.borger.dk/foa/Sider/default.aspx?fk=22&foaid=11523251)
html2 = kommuneside.read()
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(html2)
hjemmesidelink = soup2.findAll('a', attras={'ID':'_uscAncHomesite'})
print hjemmesidelink
```

This returns just an empty list:
    []

If I try like this:

```
print hjemmesidelink['href']
```

I get: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

I would've thought, that it was pretty straightforward, but I'm a rookie, and it has bugged me for days now.

Comment: `print hjemmesidelink['href']` obviously returns TypeError. It is a list, and whatever comes after it inside brackets [] is considered the index of the list. It must then be an integer (a number), not `'href'`.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, but when I try with print hjemmesidelink[0] I get: TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: That is most likely happening because the script is not effectively fetching the url.

Comment: Any idea why it isn't fecthing the url? If I just write findAll('a') and print, I get lots of stuff. I just can't seem to get the specific url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of typos in your code, so I can't say for sure why your search doesn't match anything, but the most likely problem is that you're searching for the attribute "ID" (uppercase), but the attribute in the markup is "id" (lowercase).

Since you only want to find one tag, I recommend you use [find()](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find), which will return the tag on its own, instead of a list containing the tag. This is how I would write the code:

```
print soup.find('a', id='_uscAncHomesite')                                      
# <a href="0" id="_uscAncHomesite" target="_blank">...</a>
```

Incidentally, your use of findAll makes me think you're using Beautiful Soup 3. I recommend [Beautiful Soup 4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for all new projects.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I fixed the typos, but now it returns 'None' instead of [] when I use find instead of findAll. I think I read somewhere, that find only find the first item, which is why I used findAll.

Comment: Using find instead of findAll, I am now able to retrieve the specific link with the code like this: hjemmesidelink = soup2.find('a', id='_uscAncHomesite')
print hjemmesidelink['href']

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the source code of that page and there is no `_uscAnc1Homesite`.
However, there is a `_uscAncHomesite`. Maybe you accidentally inserted that `1`?

Try it with:

```
import re

hjemmesidelink = soup2.findAll('a', id='_uscAncHomesite')
regex = r'\[<a href="([^"]+)"'
pair = re.findall(regex, hjemmesidelink)
```

This should identify your link perfectly.

Comment: That 1 must have been a typo, but either way the result is the same. It just returns an empty list.

Comment: @kabp, try with `hjemmesidelink = soup2.findAll('a', id='_uscAncHomesite')`

Comment: That sorta works. I've done a lot of searching around, and I found that soup2.findAll('a', id=lambda x: x and x.startswith('_uscAncHomesite')) works the same way. 

Either way I do it, I get this output: [<a href="http://www.albertslund.dk" id="_uscAncHomesite" target="_blank"><strong><span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_FormControlHandler1__uscShowDataAuthorityDetails__uscLblHomesite">http://www.albertslund.dk</span></strong></a>]

Comment: Which means that now it's actually able to find the specific link. I still need to make it though, so that it extracts only the url. If you have any suggestions, please let me know. Either way I'll be trying out some different stuff. Maybe RegEx is a possibility, but I think I read, that's overkill in most situations. Thanks a bunch though, Edward.

Comment: No problem, @kabp. Yes, I was about to say that regular expressions can help you, but they are kind of hard to pull off, at least for a rookie like me. Although, if you want to go that way, use something like this [link](http://www.pythonregex.com/) to help you perfect the regex.

Comment: @kabp, I think your question is now answer with the last edit I made. Tell me how it went after.

Comment: I can't get your RegEx code to work. When I try what you wrote, I get: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'findAll'

BUT, it sorta works now using another method.

    hjemmesidelink = soup2.find('a', id='_uscAncHomesite')
    print hjemmesidelink['href']

This actually get me the first url with output like this: http://www.albertslund.dk

Comment: Maybe you didn't import the modules properly? Anyway, that's cool. Glad to be of help.